# leaked Intent Receiver missing a call to unregisterReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, background-service, screen-off

please before you don't like my question , please read the details .. what i am trying to do is to use a broadcast receiver when screen-off , so i want my app to start if the screen goes off .. here is my broadcast receiver code :

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public boolean screenoff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenoff = true;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenoff = false;
        }
         Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, ShakeService.class);
         intent1.putExtra("screen_state", screenoff);
            context.startService(intent1);

    }
```

and here is the service code :

```
public class ShakeService extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stu       
            return null;
    }
     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         // REGISTER RECEIVER THAT HANDLES SCREEN ON AND SCREEN OFF LOGIC
         IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
         filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
         BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BootReceiver();
         registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
     }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try{

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashScreen.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return START_STICKY;


}
}
```

and here is my splash screen activity that i call from the service :

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Intent i =new Intent(SplashScreen.this,HomeScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
     @Override
        protected void onResume() {

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BootReceiver();
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
          //  mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakeDetector);

                BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BootReceiver();
                unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            super.onPause();
        }   
}
```

and as you can noticed i have unregistered my receiver but still i keep seeing this in the logcat :

```
 leaked Intent Receiver are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver??
```

Comment: have you tried it in another method rather than `onPause`? `onStop` for instance! I also recommend you register your receiver on `onCreate` and remove it on `onDestroy`

Comment: nop i didnt !! i will try it now .. any other suggestions?

Comment: Register your reciever in onResume() and unregister in onPause().

Comment: i have already it made it like this .. but you can see the result !

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the method of registering the receiver in onResume() and unregistering it in onPause(). This helps when the app goes in and out of scope. I'm somewhat confused on what you're trying to do with your app, but initially I see that you create a new instance of the braodcast receiver in onPause() and unregister that. Try unregistering using the same instance . Also, if you want your service to remain running in the background, you may want to look into implementation of a partial wake lock, that keeps the CPU running for your app while the screen remains off. Could you provide one more details about the purpose of the app?

Comment: yes sure .. my app is for blinds people .. so i what i want to do is when the screen off the service starts and open the splash screen activity .. this is what i really need to do .. can you help me please?

Comment: Essentially, you are tring to never let the screen go to sleep. Not necessarily a good idea for numerous reasons. As I stated in my answer above, look into wake locks. Also - you'll want to set a up a broadcast receiver that is auto-enabled and not one that is enabled from the activity. The flow of your app is still somewhat confusing.

Comment: I think you need to map out how you envision the user using the app. This will help answer that question. If the app doesnt launch until the screen goes off, then this is likely the way you would want to do it

Comment: yes i want to do it like this .. please can you help me?

Comment: I don't have the time at the moment to give a full code example. Here's a good tutorial you may wabt to look at. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html